# How can I find multiple words in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to check prohibition words.

In my codes,

```
public static String filterText(String sText)   {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("test", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sText);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()){
        m.appendReplacement(buf, maskWord(m.group()));
    }
    m.appendTail(buf);
    return buf.toString();
}

public static String maskWord(String str)   {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        buf.append("*");
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

If you receive the sentence "test is test", it will be expressed as "**** is ****" using the above code.

But I want to filter out at least a few tens to a few hundred words.

The words are stored in the DB.(DB Type: Oralce)

So how do I check multiple words?

Comment: Compile a `List` of `Pattern`(s).

Comment: *"So how do I check multiple words?"* Step 1: **Learn regex**. Step 2: Use what you've learned, i.e. the [`|`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical) pattern, and maybe the [`\b`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) pattern.

Comment: *FYI:* Your `maskWord()` method is very inefficient. --- Use `StringBuilder`, not `StringBuffer`. It's extremely rare for `StringBuffer` to be used. --- Why call `toCharArray()` when all you ever use is the `length`? Just call `str.length()` instead. --- Actually, just create array of right length, then fill it using `Arrays.fill()`, and return string using `new String()`.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your comments. First, I tried to mask except the first letter. So I wrote toCharArray (). (But, now i want to mask all letters)  So, I can use str.length () like you say. 
Secondly, the use of Arrays.fill you talked about does not understand exactly what it means. Sorry, can you explain further?

Comment: @Andreas In addition, the use of multiple words in regex has been applied. `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[test,apple,banana]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` This way, the three words test, apple, banana are properly filtered.

Comment: Sorry. It is `Pattern.compile("test|apple|banana")`, not `Pattern.compile("[test,apple,banana])"`

Comment: @eastglow With simple use of `Arrays.fill()`, your method could be `char[] buf = new char[str.length()]; Arrays.fill(buf, '*'); return new String(buf);` --- Since all your question was asking for, was the `|` pattern, and now that you've learned this *beginner* regex pattern, you should delete the question. And please remember that StackOverflow is not a replacement for learning on your own.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Java 9 you could use `Matcher.replaceAll` to replace the words in one statement. You can also use `String.replaceAll` to replace every character with '*'.

A pattern can contain many alternatives in it. You could construct a pattern with all the words required.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(word1|word2|word3)");
String result = pattern.matcher(input)
    .replaceAll(w -> w.group(1).replaceAll(".", "*"));
```

Alternatively, you could have a list of patterns and then replace each in turn:

```
for (Pattern pattern: patternList)
    result = pattern.matcher(result)
        .replaceAll(w -> w.group(1).replaceAll(".", "*"));
```

Comment: No need for Java 9, streams, or anything like that. Code in question already works for masking a word. All OP needs to learn is the `|` pattern, which you do show, but it's kind of hidden among all the other unnecessary information you're providing. Using list of patterns is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm using the Java 7 ver.